# ngrx lazy load access to root state

Tags: lazy-loading, ngrx, reducers

I'm developing an application with ngrx that leverages lazy loaded reducers, which works fine so far.

I'm running into a scenario where I need to access both the root state and a feature state from a component in a lazy loaded module.

What would be the right approach to this?

If I have my FeatureState interface extend my RootState interface, will that give me access to the RootState objects?

OR

Do I need to inject into my Component controller both Store RootState and Store FeatureState?

Answer (score 1):

You just inject both into your component and use from there.